# How to make a pdf non-modifiable yet signable using Java?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to create a pdf which is not editable but signable. The desired state should be something like this:
[image]

But currently I'm using itext, and to allow signatures I need to do PdfWriter.ALLOW_MODIFY_CONTENTS | PdfWriter.ALLOW_MODIFY_ANNOTATIONS but naturally this also makes the pdf editable.

```
int pdfPermissions = PdfWriter.ALLOW_MODIFY_CONTENTS | PdfWriter.ALLOW_MODIFY_ANNOTATIONS;
pdfStamper.setEncryption(null, null, pdfPermissions, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
```

Is there some other library which can help me achieve the desired restrictions?

Comment: What do you mean by "editable"? Fill in form fields or edit the actual PDF content? Try the option "ALLOW_FILL_IN"

Comment: Have you inspected _all_ the relevant properties of the example PDF you show the screenshot of? The encryption permissions are only one part of them, also of interest are attributes of existing signatures (approval, certification, usage rights) and of the viewer you used. It is a "Document Restrictions _Summary_" after all...